# Build A 'predefined' list as table

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if there is another way to build a table with custom content (said static) as below in a more professional way :

[image]

```
SELECT 'None' As X
  FROm dual
 UNION 
 SELECT 'Physical Delivery' As X
  FROm dual
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Variation Margin' As X
  FROm dual
  UNION 
 SELECT 'Fees' As X
  FROm dual
  UNION   
 SELECT 'Option Premium' As X
 FROm dual
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's the way to go in Oracle.

Comment: I tried to find something with less unions :)

Comment: Yep. That is the Oracle way, because Oracle lacks the `VALUES` clause which we'd use otherwise. You want `UNION ALL` though. `UNION` without `ALL` removes duplicates and there are no duplicate values in your list of course, so don't give the DBMS more work than necessary.

Comment: You ask about building a table, but then you show just a SELECT, which doesn't build a table, it builds a result set - which exists only in the memory of your session.  If you really want to build an actual table, you'd use the proper INSERT statement.  Or put the values in a flat file then load them into your table with either the sqlldr utility or making the flat file an external table, then using a SELECT from that table to populate the permanent table.  It all depends what it is you _really_ want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**SYS.ODCIVarchar2List**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm) as long as your list is less than or equal to 32767 items and each item is less than or equal to 4000 characters. It has been around since at least Oracle 10g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE (sys.odcivarchar2list ('None',
                                    'Physical Delivery',
                                    'Variation Margin',
                                    'Fees',
                                    'Option Premium'));
```

Answer (score 1):

For small test cases, ie not for production use, I use collections, since it's shorter to type and read:

```sql
select column_value as str from table(sys.ku$_vcnt('a','b','c'));
```

It has own limitations, so I don't recommend them in case of complex queries where you might need JPPD and other complex transformations

Comment: Another option is to  use xmltable or json_table

Comment: Did not understand how to use this type of select in my case !?!

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd just run this: `select column_value as str from table(sys.ku$_vcnt('None',
'Physical Delivery','Variation Margin','Fees','Option Premium'));`